# auth0 getAccessTokenSilently returns empty object when trying to set vue apollo client bearer token

Tags: vue.js, apollo-client, auth0, hasura, vue-apollo

We have a Vue application that connects to a Hasura API via the vue apollo client and uses auth0 for authentication.

The app runs fine when we give the apollo client the Hasura admin secret header (see `x-hasura-admin-secret` commented out below).

However when we try to use the bearer token it fails because `auth0.getAccessTokenSilently()` returns an empty object even though we can successfully login via auth0's redirect.

We know the auth0 login is working because `useAuth0` on the `.vue` pages returns the correct logged in user data as expected (we can currently only get to these pages by uncommenting the `x-hasura-admin-secret` headers).

See our main.js below:

```
import { createApp, provide, h } from 'vue'
import './tailwind.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import { routes } from './routes.js'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';
import { split } from 'apollo-link'
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

const auth0 = createAuth0({
  domain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin
})

function getToken(){
  // let token = localStorage.getItem('Auth_token')
  let token = auth0.getAccessTokenSilently()
  console.log("token="+JSON.stringify(token))
  return token
}

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URI,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    // "x-hasura-admin-secret": import.meta.env.VITE_HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET,
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${getToken()}`,
  }
})

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: import.meta.env.VITE_API_WS,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    inactivityTimeout: 30000,
    lazy: true,
    connectionParams: {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        // "x-hasura-admin-secret": import.meta.env.VITE_HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET,
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${getToken()}`,
      }
}
  },

})

const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query)
    return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
)

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Subscription: {
      goal: {
        goals: {
          fields: {
            merge(existing, incoming) {
              return incoming;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true,
})

const app = createApp({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },

  render: () => h(App),
})

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})

app.use(router)
app.use(
  auth0
);
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

`getAccessTokenSilently` returns a promise. You need to `await` it in order to get the actual value.

You may need to use the Apollo `setContext` link in order to inject some async processing before things are passed over to the HttpLink.

I haven't used Vue before but a similar approach from a React app could look something like this:

```js
  const authLink = setContext(async (_request, { headers }) => {
    const token = await auth0.getAccessTokenSilently();

    const newHeaders = {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };

    return {
      headers: newHeaders,
    };
  });
  
  // create your HttpLink as before but concat it so that the auth
  // one runs first
  const httpLink = new HttpLink(/** stuff **/);  

  const finalLink = authLink.concat(httpLink);
```